# Pass Optional Variable in Matlab Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, arguments, genetic-algorithm

I have a problem in coding my Genetic Algorithm using Matlab. I am using the `ga` function and I have no problem with the concepts of `ga` and how it works. For implementing my object function, I need to pass an extra variable to this function (In addition to the parameters vector). (What I intend is actually trying to mix fittings of different plot and I am integrating the `ga` function of Matlab in another code of mine). I have tried using global variables and it works fine. But I was just wondering is there any other solution for this problem? As the global variable starts to become bigger and bigger for later tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on function handles - particularly [parameterising function handles](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html). This lets you 'bind in' extra arguments to your objective function. For example, instead of

```
ga(@myfcn, ...);
```

You might say

```
param = 17;
fh = @(x) myfcn(x, param);
ga(fh, ...);
```

and so `myfcn` always gets `17` as its second argument.

Comment: Thank you for your note. I thought about that before. The objective function is defined by myself, so there is no problem in that part. The ga function only accepts an objective funtion which its input argumnet be a vector exactly with the size of number of parameters. So i should edit the ga function and customize it myself. I hopped that may be still there is a hidden option which somebody know it. the problem is i first need to pass the argument through ga and then it should be passed to objective function.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure I understand. It would be helpful if you could update your question with an example of what you've tried, and why binding in arguments doesn't work.

Comment: btw, i eddited the ga function and used your idea too. Now it works fine. For anybody else who had this problem, just simply edit the ga function of matlab, add an argument at the end, like "extra_param". and just at the beggining of the definition of the function add : fcn = @(x)fcn(x,extra_param). It is fixed now. Thanks Edric for your hint

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer would be like this.

1. find ga function. (type "edit ga")
2. Duplicate it, to a new function like ga_customized.
3. edit the new created function like this :

   function [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = ga_customized(fun,nvars,Aineq,bineq,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,intcon,options,extra_param)

and add this code

```
fun = @(x) fun(x, extra_param);
```

also find the code part around line 230 and edit it like this:

```
if nargin < 12, extra_param = [];
    if nargin < 11, options = [];
        if nargin < 10,  intcon = [];
            if nargin < 9,  nonlcon = [];
                    if nargin < 8, ub = [];
                    if nargin < 7, lb = [];
                        if nargin <6, beq = [];
                            if nargin <5, Aeq = [];
                                if nargin < 4, bineq = [];
                                    if nargin < 3, Aineq = [];
                                    end
                                 end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```